# Вложенные коллекции в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется три сущности EF:

```
public User
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions;
}

public Permission
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<User> Users;
  public virtual ICollection<Domain> Domains;
}

public Domain
{
  public int ID {get;set;};
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int PermissionID {get;set;}
  public Permission Permission {get;set;}
}
```

В проекте используется Code First. Как видите, сущности связаны отношениями:

User**(M)-(M)**Permission

Permission**(1)-(M)**Domain

Имеется generic-репозиторий. Получаю из контекста коллекцию пользователей следующим образом:

```
List<User> AllUsers = context.GetAllIncluding<User>(u=>u.Permissions).ToList();
```

Получаю коллекцию пользователей, в каждый элемент которого включена соответствующая коллекция экземпляров класса Permission, а вот уже в этих экземплярах ссылка на коллекцию экземпляров класса Domain содержит null.

**Вопрос:** *Как получить коллекцию пользователей, каждый элемент которой будет содержать коллекцию Permissions, каждый элемент которой, в свою очередь, будет содержать коллекцию Domains и т.д.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того что бы воспользоваться *lazy loading* необходимо сделать виртуальные свойства.

---

В конкретном Вашем случае:

```
public User
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions {get;set;}
}

public Permission
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Domain> Domains {get;set;}
}

public Domain
{
  public int ID {get;set;};
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int PermissionID {get;set;}

  public virtual Permission Permission {get;set;}

}
```

Свойства помеченные модификатором `virtual`, так называемые *навигационные свойства* при обращении к которым *Entity Framework* подтянет необходимые записи автоматически

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так, если я правильно понял сигнатуры методов.

```
context.GetAllIncluding<User>(u => u.Permissions.SelectMany(p => p.Domains )).ToList();
```

Но осторожнее - там запрос может выйти ужасным...

Comment: А что если везде использовать virtual-свойства? Это сильно замедлит работу с базой? База небольшая - порядка 20-ти сущностей.

Comment: Да, замедлит. Lazy loading все замедляет.

Comment: Т.е. оптимально будет выборочно оставить модификатор virtual? А, скажем, на сущностях, которые имеют много навигационных свойств оставить без virtual и пользоваться GetAllIncluding<TEntity> ?

Comment: Если запрос простой - то да. А если еще и в запросе сложные условия есть - надо использовать загрузку в несколько этапов (сначала пользователей, потом разрешения для них всех - и т.п.)

Comment: @klutch1991 и да - virtual надо оставлять не для тех сущностей, которые имеют мало навигационных свойств - а для тех, где по этим свойствам редко ходят.